# Are constraints executed before or after customized trigger?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, order-of-execution

What is the order of execution of triggers and constraint ?
For example, if I insert a bad foreign key, will this fk be detected by pgsql before my own trigger (BEFORE or AFTER) ?

I know an exception inside a trigger will rollback any update/insert executed inside this same trigger (even for AFTER trigger) but is it the same for constraints ? Are foreign key constraints make rollback all my insert/update from my own trigger ?

thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the [Postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html) is pretty clear on this (my highlighting of the relevant part):

> The trigger can be specified to fire before the operation is attempted
>   on a row (**before constraints are checked** and the INSERT, UPDATE, or
>   DELETE is attempted); or after the operation has completed (after
>   constraints are checked and the INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE has
>   completed); or instead of the operation (in the case of inserts,
>   updates or deletes on a view). If the trigger fires before or instead
>   of the event, the trigger can skip the operation for the current row,
>   or change the row being inserted (for INSERT and UPDATE operations
>   only). If the trigger fires after the event, all changes, including
>   the effects of other triggers, are "visible" to the trigger.

So a "before" or "instead of" trigger does not do the constraints first.

Comment: Rigth I should have used the doc instead of google.
For answering my second question, the constraint (or another trigger) throwing an error will cancel the updates/inserts that my trigger (BEFORE or AFTER) would have done.

Comment: Is this normally true of other DBMSs too?

Answer (score 3):

If after trigger then execute constraint first then execute trigger.

If before trigger then execute trigger first then after execute constraint.